# Menu Alignment Centering and float issue

Tags: html, css

My site header and nav function as I want. but the layout of links and logo mis-align.

it should look as follows.

> link--link--link-----logo-----link--link--dropdown

however is displays as follows

> link--link--logo--------------dropdown--link--link

the logo will not stay centered in the middle.. and the drop down shows before links on the right.

```css
#siteHeader {
  max-width: 1600px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 93px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #d7d5d5;
}
#siteHeader a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #434343;
  min-width: 185px;
  right: 0;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #000000
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #434343;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="siteHeader">
  <div class="container-fluid normalize">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#home">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="content/images/logo.png" class="logo">
      <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#home">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <span>+</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
          <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
          <a href="#">Link 3</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox looks like reasonable solution. I removed all `float` properties, added `div` container to wrap items that appear on the right and added flexbox properties to `nav` element.

```css
#siteHeader {
  max-width: 1600px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  height: 93px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #d7d5d5;
}
#siteHeader a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right, .left{
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dropdown {
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #434343;
  min-width: 185px;
  right: 9px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #000000
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #434343;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="siteHeader">
  <div class="container-fluid normalize">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#home">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="content/images/logo.png" class="logo">
      <div class="right">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#news">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown <span>+</span>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
            <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
            <a href="#">Link 3</a> 
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```